# how to fill polygon with gradient using cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, gradient, polygon

I'm making a simple game using cocos2d and all I need now is to draw filled polygon with gradient on background. I have background layer class, subclass of CCLayer, I overwrote draw() method and put this stuff:

```
CGPoint verticesHill [] = { pointHill0, pointHill1, pointHill2, pointHill3, pointHill4, pointHill5 };
ccDrawSolidPoly(verticesHill, 6, ccc4FFromccc3B(ccc3(162,122,87)));
```

of course I defined all 6 points before. But now I need to draw this poly with gradient, how can I do it? is it possible to do it with openGL? may be I shoud subclass CCLayerGradient, set colors and clip the layer to my poly? cause layer will be rectangle